# Flash error undefined property stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I created added_to_stage eventlistener in my class however flash is giving error *... \RTMP_test.as, Line 28, Column 8  1120: Access of undefined property stage.*

```
public function RTMP_test (streamID:String, videoURL:String):void
{
    sID = streamID;
    vURL = videoURL;

    if (stage)
    {
        init_RTMP();
    }
    else
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }
}

private function onAddedToStage():void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    init_RTMP();
}
```

**Edit:** When I put "extends MovieClip" I'm getting another error.

Here's my init_RTMP function:

```
private function init_RTMP():void
{
    /*
    streamID  = "mp4:myVideo";
    videoURL = "rtmp://fms.xstream.dk/*********.mp4";
    */

    vid = new Video(); //typo! was "vid = new video();"

    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onConnectionStatus);
    nc.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
    nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{} };
    nc.connect(vURL);           
}
```

---

Ok, I put "extends MovieClip" for the class and corrected some mistakes. I'm **not** getting any errors.

Comment: Show your init_RTMP method.

Comment: It seems like you should get Argument count mismatch error. Other than it should works fine.

Comment: After you extend the MovieClip class, what error you got?

Comment: please give me some time. I'm looking at it.

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. You receive no errors, so what is happening now? What do you think should happen?